# Regular Expressions in PHP - words in brackets after comma in new line

Tags: php

```
Peter (Anna, Tom, Bill)
```

should look like this:

```
Peter 
Anna,
Tom,
Bill
```

Ok, first part, I find text in brackets using preg_grep(). What are functions to extract text from something keeping the old one?

Answer (score 0):

[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) should do the trick :

```
$str = 'Peter (Anna, Tom, Bill)';
echo preg_replace('/\((.*?)\).*/','\\1',$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :-

```
 $userinfo = "Peter (Anna, Tom, Bill)";
 preg_match_all ("/[A-z]+/", $userinfo, $pat_array);
 echo implode(',',$pat_array[0]);
```